# Custom IIdentity - where does it belong in a multi-layer application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, separation-of-concerns, multi-layer

Given a 3-layer architecture:

- Domain Logic Layer
- Data Access Layer
- User Interface Layer (ASP.NET MVC web app)

What is the correct location for placing the logic related to constructing a custom user identity, adding custom Claims, and signing it into the web application?

For example, logic like this:

```
if (something)
    customClaim = new Claim("MyClaimType1", "SomeClaimValue");
else
    customClaim = new Claim("MyClaimType2", "AnotherClaimValue");

customClaimsIdentity.AddClaim(customClaim);
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(customClaimsIdentity);
```

I want to say the UI layer, but isn't the custom logic (i.e. custom user) something of a *domain* thing?  Little confused here...

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a security cross-cutting concern usually associated with ASP.NET MVC and is usually implemented as an action filter. Based on that then the code you displayed, which also makes direct use of the `HttpContext` should be in the User Interface Layer (ASP.NET MVC web app).